# SASS Error: The target selector was not found

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I'm getting this error:

```bash
Error: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .animate--fade-in !optional" to avoid this error.
    ╷
276 │     @extend .animate--fade-in;
    │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
```

from the following snippet:

```scss
.animate--fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in 0.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

@mixin animate($type: 'fade-in', $time: 1s, $delay: 0s) {
  @if $type == 'fade-in' {
    @extend .animate--fade-in;
    animation-duration: $time;
    animation-delay: $delay;
  }
```

This worked fine in Ruby Sass, but broke after upgrade to Dart Sass. I cannot understand why it cannot see the selector that is right there with exactly same name. Nothing in the [docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) hints at what the issue is.

Tried turning `.animate--fade-inv` into a placeholder `#animate--fade-in` - no change.

Comment: Your code works just fine in sassmeister running `dart 1.32.12`. It might be a very specific version issue?

Comment: I have `"sass": "1.52.1"`. Created this issue: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/3322

Comment: Issue resolved. Upgrading SASS should fix this.